# trouble sizing my 2nd display properly

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

im using Ubuntu20.04 on my dell precision 5510, i7 6820HQ,Nvidia Quadro M1000M. this PC has the 4k Touchscreen (not sure if that matters).

I dual boot between windows 10 and Ubuntu. when using windows the extra 24" acer monitor i use works like a charm, so i dont believe it is a hardware issue. i use a HDMI to connect.

but for some reason when i use Ubuntu i can not manage to get the extra display to fit right.

my built in display setting are 3840x2160 (16:9) scaling 200%

my extra monitor is 1920x1080 (16:9), and ive tried every scaling option i have (100%-200%). ive tinkered with the available options for a while to no avail.

the issue im having is the 2nd display everything is far too big. the dock is zoomed in so far that i have to scroll to get to my favorites on the bottom of it( my dock is on the left side of my screen). i cant move any windows to my 2nd screen because they will be too large and zoomed in to the point of being unusable.

thanks for any help in advance.